# how do I declare facebookSDK in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm trying to make a log in with facebook but I keep getting a error message, " Use of undeclared identifier "`FBSDKApplicationDelegate`" does anyone know how should I do it.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FacebookSDK.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <FacebookSDK.h>

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[Parse setApplicationId:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
              clientKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];
[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Comment: As a side note: you're importing FacebookSDK twice in your code example.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 4.X Facebook has split the SDK in 3 parts:

> The SDK is now composed of three frameworks, FBSDKCoreKit,
>   FBSDKLoginKit, and FBSDKShareKit.

So if you are using the latest SDK import FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit in your AppDelegate.

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

See the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the FBSDKCoreKit.framework to Frameworks in Project Navigator and then use

`#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>`

See the full setup documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work function Login Facebook.
You need add Library:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add Library:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```

Make sure this library you include in your project or add as framework
if you not have then download from here[FacebookSDK](https://developers.facebook.com/resources/facebook-ios-sdk-current.pkg)

Answer (score 0):

you can import library:

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
```